# Streaming video file in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-core, vlc

I have problem with streaming video file in my controller to eg. VLC or HTML5 video

My code

```
public IActionResult VideoStreamContent()
{
        var path = @"C:\video1.mp4";

        var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path);

        return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/octet-stream");
}
```

Browser can download that file from this controller but when i want make it in VLC then VLC cannot open that stream

Answer (score 1):

You should try getting the proper mime type for your file before sending it down. That way clients can know how to handle the file type.

```
public IActionResult VideoStreamContent() {
    var path = @"C:\video1.mp4";

    var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path);

    var mimeType = GetMimeType(path);

    return new FileStreamResult(stream, mimeType??"application/octet-stream");
}

string GetMimeType(string fileName) {
    //Insert code here to get mime type of file
}
```

There are many questions/answers on SO about how to get the mime types if you look for it.